# Why does lowering saturation via blend mode produce different grays than lowering saturation via adjustment layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blend-modes, saturation

I'm getting very different gray tones from two different ways of reducing saturation:

[image: grayscale image from Saturation blend mode]
[image: grayscale image from Adjustment Layer]

- Left – uses a layer with blend mode set to Saturation. The layer's color has 0 saturation (e.g. white or black fill), and layer is 100% opacity.
- Right – uses an Adjustment Layer (or Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation gives same result).

Why are they different? Shouldn't both be the same as setting the Saturation to 0 in HSB color space on all the pixels?

Here's the original image for comparison:

[image: original color image]

Answer (score 2):

> Left – uses a layer with blend mode set to Saturation. The layer's color has 0 saturation (e.g. white or black fill), and layer is 100% opacity.

The layer you are using to set the blend mode **must** have a value. The fill value of *that* layer is calculated to adjust saturations on the lower layer, using the top layer as a "baseline".

> Right – uses an Adjustment Layer (or Image > Adjustments > Hue/Saturation gives same result).

There is no additional layer fill value added. It is merely the removal of Hue on the layer(s) below.

---

In short, using 2 layers is a calculation between *both* layers - there's additional data when using 2 layers. Using an adjustment layer is a calculation using what is below the adjustment layer only (no additional data).

---

Beyond this, I think it would require Adobe to explain the math behind the calculations.